# All projects gone in eclipse after closing perspectives

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-juno

by mistake I chose the Close All Perspectives option in Eclipse Juno (the latest version).  Now when I start Eclipse (I'm on Mac) there is just a blank page.  I don't see any of my projects.  How to I get back to them.  I have Time Machine backups if they would be helpful here.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem before,which i solved referring to the following post,please go through the post it might be helpful.
 http://s0n1c2122.blogspot.in/2013/02/missing-projects-in-eclipse-workspace.html

Answer (score 0):

Goto menu Windows->Show Views->Project Explorer

It will show the project explorer tab